# Ruby on Rails only show data value once if there are more than one of the same

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my ruby on rails application I am currently displaying the date and time each film is shown through:

```
<% if not @film.showings.blank? %>
    To book click on a time below:</br>
    <% @film.showings.each do |showing| %>
        <%= showing.show_date.strftime("%A %e %B %Y") %>@ <%= showing.show_time.strftime("%H:%M") %><br>            
    <% end %>
<% else %>
    <p>There are currently no showings for this film.</p>
<% end %>
```

And this displays data like the following:

```
Sunday 25 January 2015 @ 12:00
Sunday 25 January 2015 @ 16:00
Monday 26 January 2015 @ 11:00
Monday 26 January 2015 @ 22:00
Tuesday 27 January 2015 @ 22:00
Wednesday 28 January 2015 @ 11:00
Wednesday 28 January 2015 @ 12:00
Wednesday 28 January 2015 @ 16:00
Wednesday 28 January 2015 @ 19:30
```

But what I want to be able to do is if the date is repeated then it only shows it once and repeats the time, so for example the date Sunday 25 January 2015 would be shown as:

`Sunday 25 January 2015 @ 12:00 16:00`

Comment: You should create a helper for this, there's a little too much logic here for the view itself

Comment: So what could I do with a helper? Can you provide an example please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group records by date and join hours.

```
<% if not @film.showings.blank? %>
To book click on a time below:</br>
<% @film.showings.group_by{|showing| showing.show_date.strftime("%A %e %B %Y") }.to_a.each do |showing| %>
    <%= showing.first %>@ <%= showing.last.map{|s| s.show_time.strftime("%H:%M")}.join(' ')  %><br>            
<% end %>
<% else %>
    <p>There are currently no showings for this film.</p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That's a brilliant answer and works perfectly, thank you! If you wouldn't mind can you please explain what different parts of the code are doing as I'm fairly new to RoR, for example: {|showing| showing.show_date.strftime("%A %e %B %Y") }.to_a.each do |showing| and showing.last.map{|s| s.show_time.strftime("%H:%M")}.join(' '). Also you're joining the times with a space in between, is there a way I could do it so that each time goes onto a new line?

Comment: Please try to use 'pry' gem and debug on the view one by one. @film.showings.group_by{|showing| showing.show_date.strftime("%A %e %B %Y") }, this one will create hash -  date as key, and showings array in same date as value. and then .to_a will convert them to two demensional array - first one will be key of hash, second one will be value of hash. and need to loop them one by one and display. so, showing.last will be showings array of a date.

Comment: Please try to use 'pry' gem and debug on the view one by one. @film.showings.group_by{|showing| showing.show_date.strftime("%A %e %B %Y") }, this one will create hash -  date as key, and showings array in same date as value. and then .to_a will convert them to two demensional array - first one will be key of hash, second one will be value of hash. and need to loop them one by one and display. so, showing.last will be showings array of a date. and showing.last.map{|s| s.show_time.strftime("%H:%M")}, will create array of hours from showings array, and .join(' ') to add spaces between hours.

Answer (score 0):

You could place a function like this in helpers or a decorator if you are using them. I'm assuming you pass in the showings from `@file.showings`. This will return an array that is how you want that you could loop over in the view and display.

```
def show_times(showings)
  showings.each_with_object({}) do |showing, hash|
    key = showing.show_date.strftime("%A %e %B %Y")
    hash[key] ||= []
    hash[key] << showing.show_time.strftime("%H:%M")
  end.map do |date, times|
    "#{date} @ #{times.join(' ')}"
  end
end
```

Comment: So this would go in my show.rb model? How do I call the method from the show.html.erb view? Sorry I'm pretty new to Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 0):

Given an array of datetime objects, you can use the following code to extract a nested hash of date and time showings. It probably best lives inside your **Film** model.

```
def showings_hash
  showings.pluck(:show_time).map {|datetime| datetime.to_date}.uniq.map{|date| {date => dates.select{|datetime| date == datetime.to_date}}}
end
```

This returns:

```
- 2015-01-12:
  - !ruby/object:DateTime 2015-01-12 18:00:00.000000000 Z
  - !ruby/object:DateTime 2015-01-12 19:00:00.000000000 Z
  - !ruby/object:DateTime 2015-01-12 20:00:00.000000000 Z
- 2015-01-13:
  - !ruby/object:DateTime 2015-01-13 20:00:00.000000000 Z
```

You can then iterate through each showing date in the view like so:

```
<% @film.showings_hash.each do |showing_date| %>
  <li>
    <%= showing_date %>
    <% showing_date.each do |showtime| %>
      <%= showtime.strftime("%H:%M") %>
    <% end %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```